# SUBSTRING_INDEX get nth value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code:

```
SET @startEndTimeCapacity = "'00:00:00', '08:00:00', 120";
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@startEndTimeCapacity, ",", 2);
```

results in `'00:00:00', '08:00:00'`.

How can I get the 2nd value `'08:00:00'` only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply the [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function twice:

- for splitting at the nth value
- for retrieving the last value in the previous list

Here's how:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@startEndTimeCapacity, ",", 2), ',', -1);
```

This works for any `n`. In this specific case `n=2`.

Comment: Hi @lemon the query u have given works perfectly when I use limit, Thanks.