# How do I SELECT the first element in a SET()?

Tags: mysql, indexing, set

I have a table with a `SET` field:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (`testset` set('one','two') )
```

with a few records:

```
SELECT * FROM test;
+---------+
| testset |
+---------+
| one     |
| two     |
| one,two |
+---------+
```

How can I `SELECT` the first element of each record? So in this case, that would be

```
SELECT testset[0] FROM test;
+---------+
| testset |
+---------+
| one     |
| two     |
| one     |
+---------+
```

of course, `testset[0]` doesn't work (I tried), but how could I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SUBSTRING\_INDEX get nth value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71925689/substring-index-get-nth-value)

Comment: @lemon not really, unless this is the only way to do this. I would say `SET`, being its own datatype would have some cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible inside a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)?

Comment: @lemon no, because what I think could be a solution doesn't work.

Comment: SET datatype have no keys ordering! it is common bitmask datatype where each bit is assigned with some string name. These names are NOT stored data, they're table's metadata. Your question makes no sense. But you may work with textual representation of the data like this data is not SET but VARCHAR. See @lemon's comment. https://dbfiddle.uk/BVYaggT2

Comment: @Akina what is making no sense about the question "get first element in set" ? Something we do in all programming languages all the time .....

Comment: There's no first element in set, that's the problem... otherwise we would call them sequences.

Comment: Your question is by fact "find the name of the least bit which is set". *what is making no sense about the question "get first element in set"* There is no ordering in SET. As I have said - the names are table's metadata, not data.

Comment: @Akina I'd say that is an implementation detail. As a DB user, the question doesn't seem so strange to me. But I guess using `SUBSTRING` is the way to go.

Comment: Part of the definition of a [set in mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) is that sets are not ordered. A set is a collection of elements, but the elements do not have any kind of position in the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A MySQL `SET` is implemented as an ordered list.
- It is stored in an integer, with the bottom bit representing the first item in the `SET` declaration.
- `INSERTing` and `SELECTing` both act as if the value of the column as a commalist.
- The *implementation* has ordering, the *concept* does not.
- So... `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is the answer:

To see it, try this on your table:

```
SELECT testset, SUBSTRING(testset, ',', 1) FROM test
    ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 11;
```

Comment: PS:  You can do boolean arithmetic (&, |, ...) on the columns for other _tricky kludges_.